# DirectX 11 frontface direction

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, culling

When creating a rasterizer I set the rasterizer description like so:

```
rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;
```

This works fine. But as I change `FrontCounterClockwise` to `false`. Nothing is rendered (I guess everything is culled). Do I missunderstand the purpose of `FrontCounterClockwise`? Because I was expecting, that it would take colockwise faces as front faces instead of counter clockwise ones. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the complete initialization code:

```
bool irrFireDX11::INITIALIZE(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, bool vsync)
{
HRESULT result;
IDXGIFactory* factory;
IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
IDXGIOutput* adapterOutput;
unsigned int numModes, i, numerator, denominator, stringLength;
DXGI_MODE_DESC* displayModeList;
DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
int error;
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
float fieldOfView, screenAspect;
m_vsync_enabled = vsync;
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthDisabledStencilDesc;

// Create a DirectX graphics interface factory.
result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

// Use the factory to create an adapter for the primary graphics interface (video card).
result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

// Enumerate the primary adapter output (monitor).
result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

// Get the number of modes that fit the DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM display format for the adapter output (monitor).
result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

// Create a list to hold all the possible display modes for this monitor/video card combination.
displayModeList = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[numModes];
if(!displayModeList) return false;

// Now fill the display mode list structures.
result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, displayModeList);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

// Now go through all the display modes and find the one that matches the screen width and height.
// When a match is found store the numerator and denominator of the refresh rate for that monitor.
for(i=0; i<numModes; i++)
{
    if(displayModeList[i].Width == (unsigned int)screenWidth)
    {
        if(displayModeList[i].Height == (unsigned int)screenHeight)
        {
            numerator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Numerator;
            denominator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Denominator;
        }
    }
}

// Get the adapter (video card) description.
result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;
m_videoCardMemory = (int)(adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory / 1024 / 1024);
error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
if(error != 0) return false;

delete [] displayModeList;
displayModeList = 0;
adapterOutput->Release();
adapterOutput = 0;
adapter->Release();
adapter = 0;
factory->Release();
factory = 0;

// Initialize the swap chain description.
ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

if(m_vsync_enabled)
{
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
}else{
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
}

swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = ifDEVICE->getWindowHandle();
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.Windowed = !ifDEVICE->getFullScreen();
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
};
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, featureLevel, 3,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, &g_featureLevel, &m_deviceContext);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

backBufferPtr->Release();
backBufferPtr = 0;

ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));
depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;
m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
    if(FAILED(result)) return false;
    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);
rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;
m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

fieldOfView = (float)D3DX_PI / 4.0f;
screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, screenAspect, nearValue, farValue);
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_worldMatrix);
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, (float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, nearValue, farValue);

// Clear the second depth stencil state before setting the parameters.
ZeroMemory(&depthDisabledStencilDesc, sizeof(depthDisabledStencilDesc));

depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthEnable = false;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthDisabledStencilDesc, &m_depthDisabledStencilState);
if(FAILED(result)) return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: With `FrontCounterClockwise = false`  it takes clockwise faces as front faces, so everythig is culled (if your geometry layout is couterclockwise). What exactly are you expected?

Comment: Well if i have a cube that is modelled clockwise (which is the case) with `FrontCounterClockwise = true` only the backfaces are rendered. (So i can see the back of the cube through the cube). So I expect to see the front of the cube when turning it to `false`. But instead i see nothing.

Comment: There can be a problem with your shader / directx setup code, so better to post it here

Comment: I edited in the complete dx init code. Hope that helps.

Comment: The part where you populate the vertex and index buffers are missing. Can you verify the winding order for all of the faces?

Comment: When I see faces using `FrontCounterClockwise = true`, isn't it proof enough, that these faces are counter clockwise??

Comment: why not paste the code of your vertex buffer and index buffer data?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to clarify is a back face in Direct3D is not the face behind you, the word "back" here does not mean the orientation in normal word, it means the vertex order, all faces except the front faces were treated as back faces.

regarding your question, you said the code below works fine.

```
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
```

what do you mean by "fine" here? every face was fine or just some of them are fine? if every face was fine, that means

1. You tell D3D to cull the back face
2. You define your vertex in counter-clockwise for every face

so you see every faces rendered well since they were treated as front face by you settings, then you change FrontCounterClockwise to false as below.

```
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false
```

that means, you tell d3d the faces which defined in counter-clockwise is back face, so D3D culls all of the faces, thus nothing was rendered.

NOTE:
in Direct3D 10/11, a front face was determined not only by vertex order, it also depends on the value of FrontCounterClockwise. , this is different with Direct3D 9 which determined only by vertex order.

So in Direct3D 10/11 if

FrontCounterClockwise = true

1. Faces were treated as front face if it's vertex order is
   counter-clockwise
2. Faces were treated as back face if it's vertex
   order is clockwise

FrontCounterClockwise = fase

1. Faces were treated as front face if it's vertex order is clockwise
2. Faces were treated as back face if it's vertex order is counter-clockwise

The name "FrontCounterClockwise" could confuse someone, we can separated the words as below

- FrontCounterClockwise = true,  means front face as vertex in counter-clockwise
  is true.
- FrontCounterClockwise = false, means front face as vertex in
  counter-clockwise is false, to put it another way, front face as vertex in
  clockwise is true.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, but you are just telling me, what I already knew. To make it more clear: I am rendering a sphere. By "fine" I mean, that I can see the sphere from outside, but I can't see it from the inside. (since from the inside, all the faces are backfaces because they are facing outwards, not inwards...) Now: if i change `FrontCounterClockwise` to `false` I expect NOT to see the sphere from outside, but INSIDE since those faces should now face inwards. But instead from any perspective I see NOTHING. Am I still misunderstanding it?

Comment: If you did as you said, I believe you will see the expected result, but I am not sure you whether you did it correct, since there are lots of aspect may affect this, such as lighting and view parameters, I did a test with DXUT sphere, everything works as expected.

Comment: Lighting and stuff like that shouldn't affect this in my case, since when I set `CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;`, I can see every face from every direction. Is there any other setting I could have set wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, I recommend you to do a test with the DXUT sphere, that's very easy and won't take you much time. you can get the DXUT sources from SDK_install_dir/Samples/C++/DXUT